# Applying test classes to dynamic page elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, tdd, selenium

I am working with a tester who is using Selenium in my latest project.

I was trying to get some information out of him as to how i needed to name my CSS classes applied to the dynamic elements on the page that he will be testing.

I think he is rather new to this himself so was going to put our findings here for comment:

- Testing classes to be used for
  dynamically generated content.
- Testing classes to be applied to HTML
  via jQuery in separate JS file.  This
  avoids testing classes being present
  in the production environment as the
  JS file can be excluded prior to
  deployment.
- Testing classes are to be unique.  To
  make classes unique there may be a
  need to create incremental classes in
  dynamically generated lists for
  example.
- Where test classes are applied purely
  for testing i.e. they apply no CSS
  formatting they will be prefixed with
  “test”.
- Testing classes should also be
  meaningful to the content they are
  targeting.

I would be greatful if there is anything that could look as though it may cause issues further down the line.

Comment: Why do you need to apply classes to elements just to run tests? Seems to me if you add classes to elements then take them out before deployment, you are not really testing your code?

Comment: Thank you.

This is exactly what i wanted.  Is selenium capable then of testing dynamic data without adding classes to test for the presence of the data as well as the value?

For example say there were two DIVs on the page that contained a header thus:

<div>
<h2>Some header</h2>
</div>


<div>
<h2>Some other header</h2>
</div>

These are both dynamically generated but i would not have thought that without a class or id to distinguish them then Selenium would not be able to differentiate between the different header values?

Comment: Selenium can use Xpath to find those, having the test css classes would make the tests faster but like @Rodreegez its not testing the app as it would be in the wild

Comment: Building on what @AutomatedTester said, there are 2 advantages to having meaningful css class names: 1) the test itself will be faster, as css selectors are faster than xpath selectors and 2) test creation/design will be easier for the tester implementing the test. I fail to see any drawbacks to having meaningful css class names. And if not a class name, then try to give meaningful id attributes everywhere possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have decioded on a combination of XPATH and using the classes that are already present.